# Need To Eliminate Directories From File Listing in C

Tags: c, unix, file

I have a problem, in that I need to get a list of the files in a Directory.  Using this [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) as a base, I've currently got this code:

```
void get_files(int maxfiles) {
    int count = 0;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    dir = opendir(DIRECTORY);
    if (dir != NULL) {

        /* get all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            if (count++ > maxfiles) break;

            printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        printf("ERROR: Could not open directory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Now it works almost exactly how I want it too, but the problem is that its also listing **directories** in with he files, and I only want file entries.  Is there a easy modification I can make to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter directories using code similar to
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036625/differentiate-between-a-unix-directory-and-file-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

POSIX defines `fstat` which can be used for the purpose of checking whether a file is a directory. It also has a macro to simplify the check.
http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat
Note that for Windows you may have to use windows API here.

Answer (score 0):

If your `struct dirent` contains the nonstandard-but-widely-available `d_type` member, you can use this to filter out directories. Worth having an option to use it and only falling back to `stat` on systems that don't, since using `d_type` rather than stat will possibly make your directory listing tens or hundreds of times faster.